# What is the difference between ergodicity and the law of large numbers?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, ergodic-theory, law-of-large-numbers

I want to begin by saying that I know absolutely no measure theory.

To my knowledge, roughly speaking a stochastic process is ergodic if its time average converges to the expectation (space average) over a long period of time.

For an iid sequence $X_{1} \ldots X_{n}$ with finite mean, I noticed that if consider the index as time then the average of this sequence $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}$ is the very definition of time average. The law of large numbers states this will converge to $E[X_{i}]$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$.

So, I am not sure how the law of large numbers is different from ergodicity? Looks to me they are saying the same thing. Can a stochastic process be ergodic if it isn't iid?

I am also not sure how the definition of ergodicity coincides with the definition given in the context of markov chains, where the chain is ergodic if it is aperiodic, irreducible, and finite mean recurrence time.

Comment: Definitions vary.  I would say a discrete time Markov chain $Z(t)$ is _ergodic_ if it is irreducible and aperiodic, in which case we are sure that for each state $i$ we have $$\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} P[Z(t)=i|Z(0)=z_0] = \lim_{t\rightarrow\infty} \frac{1}{t}\sum_{\tau=0}^{t-1} 1_{\{Z(\tau)=i\}} \quad (wp1)$$ even if there is no stationary distribution (in that case both sides are 0) and regardless of the intial state $z_0$.

Comment: Also, defining $\{Y_i\}$ iid uniform over $[0,1]$ and $\{X_i\} = \{Y_1, Y_1, Y_2, Y_2, Y_3, Y_3, ...\}$ (so that we repeat pairs) means $\{X_i\}$ is not iid but $E[X_i]=1/2$ is the same for all $i$ and certainly the time average $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ converges to $1/2$ with prob 1.

Comment: Q.: "What is the difference between ergodicity and the law of large numbers?" A.: The LLN for i.i.d. processes is (that is, may be seen as) a special case of the ergodic theorem. IOW, the class of ergodic processes is vastly larger than the class of i.i.d. processes.

Comment: @Did, if possible could you explain what sort of other processes besides iid fall into the class of ergodic processes? Or perhaps point me to a reference text?

Comment: Say, the simple random walk on a discrete circle.

Answer (score 4):

A stochastic process is a collection $\{X_t\}_t$ of real-valued (for this discussion) random variables defined on a common probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. For this discussion, we'll have the indexing be over the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$: $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$. For the definitions we consider, we insist that each $X_n$ has the same mean, denoted $E[X]$. A process $(X_n)_n$ is *stationary* if, for any $m \ge 1$ and any Borel sets $A_1,\dots,A_m$, it holds that $P(X_1 \in A_1, \dots, X_m \in A_m) = P(X_2 \in A_1,\dots,X_{m+1} \in A_m)$; in other words, $(X_n)_n$ is stationary if the law of $(X_1,X_2,X_3,\dots)$ is the same as the law of $(X_2,X_3,\dots)$ (where the value space is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ with product sigma-algebra).

We say that $(X_n)_n$ is *ergodic* if $(X_n)_n$ is stationary and $(\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N},\mathcal{B}^\mathbb{N},P^\mathbb{N},T)$ is [ergodic as a measure preserving system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Ergodic_transformations), where $P^\mathbb{N}(A) := P((X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega),\dots) \in A)$ and $T$ is the left shift: $T((x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)) := (x_2,x_3,\dots)$ (note that $(X_n)_n$ stationary implies $T$ preserves $P^\mathbb{N}$). A consequence of this notion of ergodicity is that for each measurable $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, it holds that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} f(X_n(\omega)) \to E[f(X)]$ with probability $1$.

We say that $(X_n)_n$ is *mean-ergodic* if $E\left[|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} X_n - E[X]|^2\right] \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$. Note that $(X_n)_n$ need not be stationary.

We say that $(X_n)_n$ is *pointwise-ergodic* if $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} X_n(\omega) \to E[X]$ with probability $1$. Note that ergodic implies pointwise-ergodic.

We say that $(X_n)_n$ is *LLN-applicable* if the $X_n's$ are i.i.d. and the set of $\omega \in \Omega$ satisfying $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} X_n(\omega) \to E[X]$ has measure/probability $1$.

It is not clear what is usually meant by "ergodic". [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_process) uses "ergodic" to mean mean-ergodic.

As the comments indicate, there are $(X_n)_n$ that are pointwise-ergodic but not i.i.d. and thus not LLN-applicable. For example, we can take any $Y_n$'s that are i.i.d. and then consider $(X_1,X_2,\dots) = (Y_1,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3,\dots)$.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3347801/366088) gives an example of $(X_n)_n$ that are stationary, pointwise-ergodic, but not ergodic. The example is also mean-ergodic if $E[Y_i] = 0$ and $E[Y_i^2] < \infty$.

Let $Y_1,Y_2,\dots$ be independent with, for each $i$, $P(Y_i = 1) = \frac{1}{2}$ and $P(Y_i = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$. Let $X_n = \frac{Y_1+\dots+Y_n}{\sqrt{n\log\log\log n}}$. Then indeed $E[X_n]$ is the same for each $n$ (the common mean is $0$) and $(X_n)_n$ is mean-ergodic, since $E[|X_n-0|^2] = E[X_n^2] = \frac{n}{n\log\log\log n} \to 0$. However, $(X_n)_n$ is not pointwise-ergodic, since with probability $1$, $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \frac{Y_1+\dots+Y_n}{\sqrt{2n\log\log n}} = 1$. (It's obviously not ergodic, since it's not stationary).

If the $X_n$'s are bounded, then the dominated convergence theorem implies that pointwise-ergodic implies mean-ergodic.

---

A *Markov chain*, for this discussion, is a stochastic process $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ taking values in a common, finite set $X$ such that (1) $P(X_n=x) > 0$ for each $n \ge 1$ and $x \in X$ and (2) for each $n,x_1,\dots,x_n$, it holds that $P(X_n = x_n | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1},\dots,X_1=x_1) = P(X_n = x_n | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1})$. We will make the common assumption/imposition that the Markov chain is *time homogeneous*, meaning $P(X_n = x_n | X_{n-1} = x_{n-1})$ is independent of $n$ and also that $P(X_1 = x) = P(X_2 = x)$ for each $x \in X$. An easy exercise shows that the time homogeneity assumption implies that $(X_1,X_2,\dots)$ is stationary (hint: use induction).

Associated to a Markov chain, we can define a weighted, directed graph on $X$ with the weight of the directed edge from $x$ to $y$ being $P(X_2 = y | X_1 = x)$ if the probability is positive (if it's not, don't draw a directed edge).

A Markov chain is *strongly connected* if one can get from one vertex to any other vertex, travelling along the graph.

.

$\bf{Claim}$: A Markov chain is ergodic if and only if it is strongly connected.

Proof: Suppose the Markov chain is ergodic. Take any $x_0,x_1 \in X$. Let $f = 1_{x_1}$. Then, with probability $1$, $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} f(X_n(\omega)) \to E[f(X)] = P(X = x_1)$. Since $P(X=x_1) > 0$, $P(\exists n \ge 2 : X_n = x_1 | X_1 = x_0) > 0$, which, by countable additivity, means there is some $n \ge 2$ with $P(X_n = x_1 | X_1 = x_0) > 0$, but $P(X_n = x_1 | X_1 = x_0) = \sum_{y_2,\dots,y_{n-1}} P(X_n = x_1 | X_{n-1} = y_{n-1})\dots P(X_2 = y_2 | X_1 = x_0)$, so there is some $y_2,\dots,y_{n-1}$ with each of the terms in the product being nonzero, which means there is a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$. Therefore, the Markov chain is strongly connected. The other direction uses Perron-Frobenius and some ergodic theory, which I omit.

Comment: You say: "This is the same as saying that $(\mathbb R^\mathbb N,\mathfrak B^\mathbb N,P^\mathbb N,T)$ is ergodic". I don't know how to use the definition you gave for ergodicity on that tuple, since you defined ergodicity for a stochastic process, not for a probability space with a transformation. Are you using a different definition of ergodicity for the second one? The wikipedia page seems to be closer to the second one: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergodic_theory#Ergodic_theorems. Also, why are those two statements equivalent?

Comment: @user56834 Yes, thanks. I should have specified that before. I was indeed using the definition of ergodicity for a general measure-preserving system. I have updated my answer. In regards to the equivalence, I'm not sure. I remember seeing in some book some time ago that they were equivalent I think, but I'm not sure. I updated my answer to reflect the one implication I know to be true.