# is ergodicity just the law of large numbers?

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory, law-of-large-numbers

There are various laws of large numbers. They have the form

> LLN. If [*conditions on $X_i$*] then $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\mathbb E [X_i]$

Is it correct to say that $X_i$ satisfies ergodicity if $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\mathbb E [X_i]$?

In other words, that ergodicity is just the conclusion you get if you apply the law of large numbers? I know that ergodicity is formalized differently, but I am trying to connect it to something I know.

Comment: An iid sequence can be realized as an ergodic sequence.  But not conversely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  It's possible for a process $\ \left\{X_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\ $ to be non-ergodic but still satisfy the condition $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\mathbb E [X_i]\ $.

If $\ \left\{Y_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\ $ is a sequence of independent random variables such that $\ Y_{2i-1}, i=1,2,\dots\ $ have identical distribution $\ F\ $, say, and $\ Y_{2i}, i=1,2,\dots\ $ have identical distribution $\ G\ne F\ $, but with $\ \mathbb E [Y_{2i-1}]=\mathbb E [Y_{2i}]\ $, and  $\ X_i = Y_{2i-1}\ $ for all $\ i\ $ with probability $\ p\in \left(0,1\right)\ $, and $\ X_i = Y_{2i}\ $ for all $\ i\ $ with probability $\ 1-p\ $, then $\ \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i=\mathbb E [X_i]\ $ with probability $1$, but $\ \left\{X_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\ $ is not ergodic.

**Why $\ \left\{X_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\ $ is not ergodic.**

One of the consequences of ergodicity is that 
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(X_i\right)=\mathbb E[f\left(X_i\right)]\ $$
with probability $1$, not only for $\ f(x)\equiv x\ $, but also for $\ f\ $ *any* measurable function for which $\ E[\,\left\vert f\left(X_i\right)\right\vert\,] <\infty\ $.  For a process $\ \left\{Y_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\ $ satisfying the conditions given above there must be some measurable set $\ A\ $ such that $\ \mathbb P\left(Y_{2i-1}\in A\right) \ne \mathbb P\left(Y_{2i}\in A\right) \ $.  Let $\ f:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R\ $ be defined by
$$
f(x)=\cases{1 & if $\ x\in A\ $,\\
            0 & if $\ x\not\in A\ $.}
$$
Then $\ \mathbb E[f\left(X_i\right)]=p\,\mathbb P\left(Y_{2i-1}\in A\right) + (1-p)\,\mathbb P\left(Y_{2i}\in A\right)\ \ $, but with probability $\ p\ $,
$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(X_i\right)= \mathbb P\left(Y_{2i-1}\in A\right)\ne \mathbb E[f\left(X_i\right)]\ ,
$$
and with probability $\ 1-p\ $,
$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(X_i\right)= \mathbb P\left(Y_{2i}\in A\right)\ne \mathbb E[f\left(X_i\right)]\ .
$$

Comment: Why is $X_i$ not ergodic?

Comment: @lonza leggiera what is your definition of ergodic?

Comment: @mathworker21 My definition is: Let $\ \mu\ $ be the measure defined on $\ \mathbb R^\infty\ $ by $\ \mu(A)= \mathbb P(\left\{X_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\in A)\ $, and $\ S:\mathbb R^\infty\rightarrow \mathbb R^\infty\ $ be the left-shift operator on $\ \mathbb R^\infty\ $. Then $\ \left\{X_i\right\}_{i=1}^\infty\ $ is ergodic if it is stationary and $\ S\ $ is ergodic with respect to $\ \mu\ $.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera so the consequence you gave is an equivalent definition, right? I.e., that you have time average converges to mean for every measurable $f$

Comment: @mathworker21 I don't believe it's equivalent, although my acquaintance with the field isn't sufficiently deep for me to be sure of that off the top of my head. What I believe *is* equivalent is
$$
 \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n f\left(\left\{X_j\right\}_{j=i}^\infty\right)=\mathbb E\left [f\left(\left\{X_j\right\}_{j=1}^\infty\right)\right]
$$
for every measurable $\ f:\mathbb R^\infty\rightarrow\mathbb R^\infty\ $.